# How to install the steam client?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, games, steam

I am trying to install steam for Ubuntu, yet I get forbidden messages when following these two tutorials:

1. [Valve's guide for Steam for Linux](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux)

   ```
   http --download http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/archive/precise/steam_latest.deb
   HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
   ```
2. [Ubuntu's wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Valve)

   ```
   http --download http://media.steampowered.com/client/installer/steam.deb
   HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
   ```

it seems those guides are outdated. How to install the latest steam client on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

In the [issue from valve's steam for linux](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/4719#issuecomment-263175318) there's the link provided which works:

```
http --download http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/pool/steam/s/steam/steam-launcher_1.0.0.48_all.deb
```

Be careful when installing third-party deb package, as they can harm your system. repo.steampowered.com is owned by Valve, hence it should be fine.

Comment: @Liso It's self-answered. I only will be able to accept it in two days. It's a rule to allow for better answers to arrive in time.

Comment: Why use a .deb at all? It is in the repos.

Comment: @MarkKirby Because I didn't know. Please provide it as an answer.

Comment: It is a dupe, if there is not a specific reason to use this method.